# Vuetify v-text-field not updating value when it is changed. Even on $forceUpdate()

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-model

Vuetify v-text-field not updating value when it is changed. Even on $forceUpdate() and when using $set

I have tried to use it without $forceUpdate and $set but even with both of these methods it does not work

Example what **DOES** work **WITHOUT** vuetify:
https://jsfiddle.net/gu273qy0/3/

Example of what **DOES NOT** work **WITH** Vuetify:
https://jsfiddle.net/gu273qy0/5/

This javascript can be used in both examples

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    todos: ['']
  }),
  methods: {
    setText(index, todo){
        if (todo.toString().match(/^((([A-Z]{3})[UJZ](\d{0,7}))|[A-Z]{0,3})$/)) {
        this.$set(this.todos, index, todo)
      }

      this.$forceUpdate()
    },
    addText() {
        console.log(this.todos)
            this.todos.push('')
    }
  }
})
```

I expect that the exact same implementation works with vuetify and without vuetify. Unfortunately this is not the case. Only the non vuetify example works.

An example of a **valid** value or todo is `AAAU0101201`.

An example of a **invalid value** is `AAAA`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really explain why you have not the same results with or without Vuetify, but in fact, with Vuetify example, if you enter a wrong value, then the todos array won't be modified, and so the model won't be updated

I think you should for example handle `@blur` event:
https://jsfiddle.net/v6m2tyrs/1/

Comment: The array won't be modified but the text field does not reflect this. This is very user unfriendly. In the example you showed if the user enters a wrong input the input is cleared. This can be very confusing.

Comment: The confusion was instroduced when you created a @input handler which does not always update data. If you don't know exactly what you are doing, I would recommend you to stick with v-model.t

Comment: Although it is a bit off topic could you elaborate on what an input event should do? I do not think v-model does not work in my case because I need to do validation while also changing the value.

Comment: When do you want the field to clear when the todo is incorrect. I suppose it's not on input, because if you do so, the field will clear after the first keydown. That's why I think you need to handle @blur.

Comment: Isn't my solution doing what you want?

Comment: I want the input to stop whenever the new input does not validate properly. Just as with this solution without vuetify https://jsfiddle.net/gu273qy0/3/

Comment: This makes no sense, because to type a valid value, you need to type the first character, and at this moment the value is not valid. So the input text should be cleared? That's why I'm talking about blur